# Backbone Collection get Model by it's ID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've problems getting a single Model by its ID even though I set the idAttribute in the coresponding Model.

A Collection looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_account": "51dc04dbe4e643043d000001",
        "name": "test.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "_id": "51ff833f0342ee0000000001",
        "added": "2013-08-05T10:49:35.737Z"
    }
]

// Inside the Model I defined idAttribute
FileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

idAttribute : "_id",
urlRoot : "/api/file"

[...]

}
// The collection contain each of the Model items
// but if I try to get a single model item  by id:

Collection.get("51ff833f0342ee0000000001") -> the result is undefined
```

I cant figure out why and the solution from [Backbone.Collection get model by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299992/backbone-collection-get-model-by-id) was not the key to solve the problem.

Comment: Because in your example, you're trying to use the `_account` rather than the `_id`

Comment: Oh that was just a type error. problem is still present

Comment: Did you set the [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) type on the collection?

Comment: Yes i did like this...model : FileModel,

Comment: Depending on how your JavaScript is laid out you might need to set the model in the collection's initialize method, for example `this.model = FileModel;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve a model by a *custom id* you need to specify on the model it's [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) and you need to specify the collection's [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) property to use your model. Normally it's enough to set this in your collection where you declare it's properties

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: FileModel,
  ...
})
```

However depending on how you have your JavaScript laid out (and therefore how the JavaScript is evaluated by the browser) it is possible at the time the `model: FileModel` statement is read it is still undefined. To get around this you can move the assignment of the property to the initialize/constructor of your collection.

For example

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.model = FileModel;
        }
    ...
});
```